# Transformation vs Action in the context of Laziness

Tags: apache-spark

As mentioned in the "Learning Spark: Lightning-Fast Big Data Analysis" book:

> Transformations and actions are different because of the way Spark computes RDDs.

After some explanation about laziness, as I found, both transformations and actions are working lazily. Therefore, the question is, what does the quoted sentence mean?

Comment: who downvoted this question? it seems like a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Foreach is an action.  It gives you a way to trigger execution if your final action is going to do something from inside a custom function.  For example you may save to your own database using a custom function call in foreach instead of one of the RDD/DF write methods.

Comment: what made you think that both transformations and actions are working lazily?

Comment: While Spark Transformation builds execution plan, Action immediately triggers computation to return an output result by running that plan. Find [more info from here](https://medium.com/data-engineering-lab/navigating-the-spark-transformations-vs-actions-in-apache-spark-30f7fd8726d9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily valid to contrast laziness of RDD actions vs transformations.

The correct statement would be that RDDs are lazily evaluated, from the perspective of an RDD as a collection of data: there's not necessarily "data" in memory when the RDD instance is created.

The question raised by this statement is: when does the RDD's data get loaded in memory? Which can be rephrased as "when does the RDD get evaluated?". It's here that we have the distinction between actions and transformations:

Consider the following sequence of code:

**Line #1:**

```
rdd = sc.textFile("text-file-path")
```

Does the RDD exist? **Yes**.

Is the data loaded in memory? **No**. 

**--> RDD evaluation is lazy**

**Line #2:**

```
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda line: list.split())
```

Does the RDD exist? **Yes**. In fact, there are **2 RDDs**. 

Is the data loaded in memory? **No**. 

--> Still, it's lazy, all Spark does is record how to load the data and transform it, remembering the lineage (how to derive RDDs one from another).

**Line #3**

```
print(rdd2.collect())
```

Does the RDD exist? **Yes** (2 RDDs still).

Is the data loaded in memory? **Yes**.

What's the difference? `collect()` forces Spark to return the result of the transformations. Spark now does all that it recorded in steps #1, #2, and #3.

In spark's terminology, #1 and #2 are transformations.
Transformations typically return another `RDD` instance, and that's a hint for recognizing the *lazy* part.

#3 has an action, which simply means an operation that causes **plans** in transformations to be carried out in order to return a result or perform a final action, such as saving results (yes, *"such as saving the actual collection of data loaded in memory"*).

So, in short, I'd say that RDDs are lazily evaluated, but, in my opinion, **it's incorrect to label operations (actions or transformations) as lazy or not**.

Answer (score 1):

Transformations are lazy, actions are not.

Definitions:

**Transformation** - A function that mutates the data out on the cluster.  These actions will change the data in place when they are executed.  Examples of this are map, filter, and aggregate.  These are not executed until an action is called.

**Action** - Any function that results in data being persisted or returned to the driver (also foreach, which doesn't really fall into those two categories).

In order to run an action (like saving the data), all the transformations you have requested up till now have to be run to materialize the data.  Spark can implement optimizations if it looks at the total execution plan of the operations you want to run, so it is beneficial not to compute anything until it is required.