# using functools reduce on Distributed Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to add list of columns into existing Spark DataFrame.

**Example code:**

```
columns_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
reduce(lambda df, col: df.withColumn(col, lit('NULL')), columns_list, df).show()
```

This is giving the expected results.

Does using `reduce()` on Distributed Spark DataFrame will try to execute everything on `Single Node?`

Comment: any specific reason to use `reduce`? just `df.select("*",*[lit('NULL').alias(i) for i in columns_list]).show()` seem to work fine.

Comment: @anky: that's a nice solution, i love it.. thanks..

Answer (score 2):

OP asked

> Does using reduce() on Distributed Spark DataFrame will try to execute everything on Single Node?

But I think what OP really wants to know is

> whether the following commands are different from an Spark execution standpoint?

#### Generate toy data

```
data = [
    ('1',),
    ('2',),
    ('3',),
    ('4',),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id'])
```

You can see the execution plan of your code using `.explain()`

#### Scenario 1 (using `functools.reduce`)

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit
columns_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
reduce(lambda df, col: df.withColumn(col, lit('NULL')), columns_list, df).show()
result1 = reduce(lambda df, col: df.withColumn(col, lit('NULL')), columns_list, df)
result1.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#0, NULL AS col1#122, NULL AS col2#125, NULL AS col3#129, NULL AS col4#134]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[id#0]
```

#### Scenario 2 (@anky's code using `select` and list comprehension)

```
result2 = df.select("*",*[lit('NULL').alias(i) for i in columns_list])
result2.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#0, NULL AS col1#140, NULL AS col2#141, NULL AS col3#142, NULL AS col4#143]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[id#0]
```

#### Scenario 3 (using for loop and iterative assignment)

```
result3 = df
for i in columns_list:
    result3 = result3.withColumn(i, lit('NULL'))

result3.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#0, NULL AS col1#167, NULL AS col2#170, NULL AS col3#174, NULL AS col4#179]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[id#0]
```

Note that **Scenario 3** does not work in 'base' Python (why `functools.reduce()` is necessary). OP, I suggest reading about the [differences between Transformations and Actions in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753298/transformation-vs-action-in-the-context-of-laziness). Spark generates a 'Plan' of execution first, which is why `Reduce()` is not required.

Comment: Hello, may you please explain to me why in your definition of `reduce` function you passed 2 more arguments after your lambda function. I am struggling with a similar case, but when I check the documentations for `reduce` it only has 2 arguments for lambda and an iterable. Thank you very much in advance.